# tagsinput not working in jquery steps

Tags: jquery-steps, bootstrap-tags-input

I want my tagsinput in jquery steps form, but it's not working. please help

```
               <fieldset>
                    <h2>Account Information</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Request Purpose</label>
                                <input id="trip_purpose2" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control required"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
```

and my bootstrap tagsinput after jquery steps.

```
 $("#form").steps();
 $("#trip_purpose2").tagsinput();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux6ga.jpg)
after I push enter, nothing happen, still like that. I want the tagsinput working on jquery steps. thanks everyone